# Is whiskey/beer without alcohol haram?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol

Dear brother can someone take whiskey/beer which have no alcohol in it?

Comment: Which "hadith" do you want to have interpreted? Use relevant tags!

Comment: Beer witouth alchool is never fully witouth alchool, they have at least 0.01% alchool in it. (Usually says in the bottle depending on the laws of your country)

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly said in Islam, that even a tiny bit of something which potentially makes you drunk in large number of quantity, it is haram.

Comment: It's not that simple: there's a tiny bit of alcohol in e.g. dates due to fermentation, which the Prophet is recorded as eating.

Comment: that same as saying, I could consume weed in 0.1% composition combined with tea. ISLAM has common sense.

Answer (score 0):

If it was made by taking already alcoholic beer or wine and then burning the alcohol off, then yes, its still haram.

Answer (score -1):

The final Beer contains a minimum amount of alcohol at 0.05%
Yes of course.
if you are making beer by yourself without alcohol that may be it is okay
but for whiskey,It is prohibited.
Because when you drink something make you unconscious you will do all wrong things . you may kill or stole ...etc.